# How to put the output of a custom rule in `bazel-genfiles/` instead of `bazel-out/`?

Tags: bazel

We are generating a number of Go source files as part of our build. Previously we used a `genrule` ([example here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/nYzutTX6JZ4/9lscxhxrCAAJ)) which resulted in the generated files being stored in `bazel-genfiles/`.

We recently switched to using a custom rule as demonstrated in `rules_go` (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/tree/master/examples/bindata). This change means that the output source files are stored in `bazel-bin/` instead of `bazel-genfiles/`.

This change of output location has broken Go integration in some of the IDEs used by our developers. Notably, [`gocode`](https://github.com/nsf/gocode), the autocompletion engine used by `vim-go` and VSCode, when running in `bzl` (Bazel) lookup mode seems to expect to find generated sources in `bazel-genfiles/`, not `bazel-bin/`, and therefore fails.

How do I modify my rule to save the output to `bazel-genfiles/` instead of `bazel-bin/`? My rule is equivalent to the example in `rules_go`:

```
    def _bindata_impl(ctx):
      out = ctx.new_file(ctx.label.name + ".go")
      ctx.action(
        inputs = ctx.files.srcs,
        outputs = [out],
        executable = ctx.file._bindata,
        arguments = [
            "-o", out.path, 
            "-pkg", ctx.attr.package,
            "-prefix", ctx.label.package,
        ] + [src.path for src in ctx.files.srcs],
      )
      return [
        DefaultInfo(
          files = depset([out])
        ) 
      ]

    bindata = rule(
        _bindata_impl,
        attrs = {
            "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True, cfg = "data"),
            "package": attr.string(mandatory=True),
            "_bindata":  attr.label(allow_files=True, single_file=True, default=Label("@com_github_jteeuwen_go_bindata//go-bindata:go-bindata")),
        },
    )
```

I would expect an argument to either [`ctx.new_file`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html#new_file(filename)) or [`ctx.action`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html#action) but cannot find anything relevant in the Skylark reference or tutorial.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `output_to_genfiles=True` in the `rule()` definition. It is mentioned in the [rule docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#rule).

So:

```
bindata = rule(
        _bindata_impl,
        attrs = {
            "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True, cfg = "data"),
            "package": attr.string(mandatory=True),
            "_bindata":  attr.label(allow_files=True, single_file=True, default=Label("@com_github_jteeuwen_go_bindata//go-bindata:go-bindata")),
        },
        output_to_genfiles = True,
    )
```